# Run ASP.NET page with parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters

I need to run an ASP.NET page with some parameter.

For example :

When I run the project `Default.aspx` opens in the browser.
I want to open `Default.aspx?CONFERENCEID=3`

*Is this possible?*

Comment: Are you looking to use querystring parameters?

Comment: I'am using query string but i need to test page.I did not want to write manually every time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the website  project..Select **Property** pages..select **Startup options**..
Set **specific page** property as

`Default.aspx?CONFERENCEID=3`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it man

Add this code in your default screen pageload event

```
Page-load()//Point 1
{
 if(string.IsNullorEmpty(Request.QueryString("CONFERENCEID").Tostring()))// Point 3
 {
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?CONFERENCEID="+ 3);
 }
   string value=Request.QueryString("CONFERENCEID").Tostring()//Point 2
}
```

Where,

**When you run your application**

1. The default screen pageload function will load
2. if the url have any (CONFERENCEID) query string then store the query string values into a variable
3. *otherwise  it's redirect to same page( like reload) with a query string.*

   - This is a simple logic. But other members will give another idea's.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the startup page in the project properties:
[image]
Set it to `Specific page` or `Start URL`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it in VS2015:

- Right click on Project
- Select Properties
- Click on Web on the right menu
- Select Start URL radio button
- Enter your url: http://www.yoursite/Default.aspx?CONFERENCEID=3